# Vim custom syntax highlighting, include other language syntax in a specified range

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

VIM 7.3.46

I have a custom syntax file defined for making my notes more readable.

I want to define a range that will apply syntax highlighting from an existing syntax file (e.g. php, javascript or whatever) within certain boundary characters.

For example,

```
Notes.txt
Notes would be here, blah blah...
More notes, then a javascript code block with proper js highlighting below this:

**jsbegin**
    $('#jquerystuff').change(function(){
        var example = $(this).val();
        alert(example);
    });
**jsend**
```

So I'm looking for something like this to put in the vim syntax file:

```
so <sfile>:p:h/javascript.vim
so <sfile>:p:h/php.vim

syn region notesJS matchgroup=javascript start="**jsbegin**" end="**jsend**" contains=javascript
syn region notesPHP matchgroup=php start="**phpbegin**" end="**phpend**" contains=php
```

But it must only apply javascript highlighting to text within the defined range:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required lines are as follows:

```
" Include PHP highlighting between **phpbegin** and **phpend** tags
syn include @notesPHP syntax/php.vim
syn region phpCustom start=+\*\*phpbegin\*\*+ keepend end=+\*\*phpend\*\*+ contains=@notesPHP

" Include JavaScript highlighting between **jsbegin** and **jsend** tags
syn include @notesJavaScript syntax/javascript.vim
syn region javaScriptCustom start=+\*\*jsbegin\*\*+ keepend end=+\*\*jsend\*\*+me=s-1 contains=@nJavaScript
```

Comment: I think me=s-1 means the highligh region is before jsend. Then can I use `start=+\*\*jsbegin\*\*+ms=e+1` ? I tried it but jsbegin is still highlighted in JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @LoveRight did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue.